# Python 2.x Strings: Unicode vs. Bytes

Tags: python, string, unicode, character-encoding

I deal with languages that are non-us and also sometimes still have to write in Python 2.x. Reading this article: http://www.snarky.ca/why-python-3-exists by Brett Cannon makes me wonder if that implies that if I use strings that are only characters and not bytes, should I prepend all my strings with `u`, to avoid a potential mix up betwen byte-strings and unicode-strings? And: Does this also apply for Jython?

And one last question: `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is completely independed of the above, providing only the encoding of the file itself - correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you want to keep text in `unicode` objects (the `str` type in Python 3), and maintain a Unicode sandwich (decode incoming data as soon as possible, postpone encoding until the data needs to exit your application). See [Ned Batchelder's excellent Unicode presentation](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html).

This also applies to Jython, which is just another implementation of the Python language.

The [PEP 263 source code encoding declaration](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) tells the interpreter what codec to use when decoding bytes in your source code. It helps when defining Unicode literals with non-ASCII bytes, but doesn't dictate how other data other than the source code is encoded or decoded.